# Finding the interval convergence $\sum\frac{3k^2(x)^k}{e^k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How would I find the interval of convergence for the following power series

$\sum\frac{3k^2(x)^k}{e^k}$

I performed the ratio test.

$\frac{3(k+1)^2(x)^{k+1}}{e^k}$*$\frac{e^k}{3k^2x^k}$

$x\frac{1}{e}\frac{3(k+1)^2}{3k^2}$

$-1<\frac{1}{e}x<1$

$x=e$

$\sum\frac{e^k3k^2}{e^k}$

$\sum3k^2$ diverges as limit $k\rightarrow\infty$ does not equal zero.

$\sum\frac{(-e)^k3k^2}{e^k}$

$\frac{3k^2}{e^k}$

as limit is zero it converges.

Therefore interval convergence $[-e,e)$

would this be correct.

Comment: There is divergence at $-e$, for the same reason as at $e$. For note that $\frac{(-e)^k}{e^k}=(-1)^k$.

Comment: but I can use  hospital rule to make it work or not with the (-e)^k part actually never mind b/c it does not alternate

Comment: You simplified incorrectly, at $-e$ it simplifies to $3k^2(-1)^k$.

Comment: Yes you are right I see the error I made now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interval of convergence should be $(-e, e)$, since there is divergence at $x = -e$, just as there is for $x = e$.

$$\sum \frac{(-e)^k3k^2}{e^k} = \sum \frac{(-1)^k e^k 3k^2}{e^k} = \sum (-1)^k 3k^2$$

which clearly diverges.